# Library routine called out of sequence while inserting after deletion in database

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios5

Iam creating SQLite database in my iPhone Application.If deleted Continuously one by one and after deletion of 20 items like that ,after going to insert into database, Iam getting the error message as "Library routine Called Out Of Sequence".
I don't know why Iam getting this error Whether for insert or delete.Please help me as soon as possible.

I searched solutions in that i find use NSInvocationperationQueue,if i use that data only not adding the database.so ,how can i do that, Iam not getting how to use  NSInvocationperationQueue

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You are calling a sqlite3 function out-of-sequence.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372871/library-routine-called-out-of-sequence-sqlite3-prepare-v2create-table

Comment: But My Case is different not in the while creation of table,while inserting .I opened and closed database correctly also.Otherwise tell me how to refresh database,or otherwise tell me how to know whether the database is free or not, means some operation is going on database

Comment: You should tell use which SQLite library routines you are calling. Show the code!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself recently. I was wrapping my insert and bind steps in a statement like this :

```
If (<your SQL> != SQLITE_OK) {}
```

If you sanitize your data beforehand, you can simply call the SQL routine without the loop - that'll likely fix you up.

BE CAREFUL THOUGH! This puts you in charge of checking your data for validity, or else your app might crash.